# OpenGL - Fast Sprite Drawing - need some guidance

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, sprite

My program creates and draws a particle-system with OpenGL. 
I had it fully working with glBegin() and glEnd() but then I noticed that this is outdated and should not be used at all. So I started to rewrite it with glDrawArrays();

What I have looks like this:

```
typedef QVector< Particle* > PARTICLES;
#define PARTICLE_SIZE 20.0f

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    //>> TEST
    QGLFormat glFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers);
    glFormat.setSwapInterval(1); // vsync
    //>> /TEST
    QImage textureSnow = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat( imgSnow );

    glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenTextures(3, m_texture);

    //Snow Particles
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture[1]);
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
            textureSnow.width(), textureSnow.height(),
            0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureSnow.bits());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glFinish();
    m_renderTimer->start(0);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture[1]);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glLoadIdentity();

    PARTICLES particles = m_particleSystem->getParticles();
    for(int i = 0; i < m_particleSystem->getParticleCount(); i++)
    {
        // Get specific variables for the Particle
        float x = particles[i]->getX();
        float y = particles[i]->getY();
        float scale = particles[i]->getScale();
        float correctionValue = (PARTICLE_SIZE*scale/2);

        const float verts[] = {
            x -correctionValue, y -correctionValue,
            x +PARTICLE_SIZE -correctionValue, y -correctionValue,
            x +PARTICLE_SIZE -correctionValue, y + PARTICLE_SIZE -correctionValue,
            x -correctionValue, y +PARTICLE_SIZE -correctionValue
        };

        // Since I don't use more than one sprite for this Particle at the moment
        const float texVerts[] = {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f
        };

        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texVerts);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

---

This way it doesn't display anything (black screen).
I can't figure out alone what I need to do.

**What I actually want to know:**

What did I miss? or in other words:
How do I draw a huge amount of my Particles, that are always in motion, with up-to-date OpenGl, using sprites?

Comment: You have to submit the vertex data to the GPU before you can render it, via a vertex buffer object or vertex array object and then render the vertices with a shader. [This tutorial does a good job of teaching modern opengl](http://open.gl/drawing)

Comment: I'm going to take a look at this tutorial, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Which OpenGL version you want to work with?

There are minor difference in OGL 2.0ES, 2.1, 3.0 and up, but you basically need a shader and reduce changes/upload of data, for particle system those dynamic can be handled on shader side so that you don't drain the bus with unnecessary traffic.

Comment: I think it would be good, if it worked for OGL 2.0 and the other thing: I have nearly no experience in shaders. Does this mean that I should handle particles in a complete different way (by using a shader) or how was this meant?

Comment: For OGL 2.0 you can't alter position on shader, so each particle would be an independent object and there are 2 ways: animated sprits, and modifying vertex coordinates; or some hybrid of them. Note that on some platform(eg. windows) you need to explicitly create 2.0 context, glew can make your life much easier.